# "Surtout qu'en ce moment" -- what does "qu'en" really mean in this phrase?

Tags: grammaire

A short quote from a podcast for learners of French:

> Ça a l'air d'être ce qu'il me faut. Surtout **qu'en** ce moment, je réagis très mal aux bruits, j'ai vraiment besoin de tranquillité. Et côté culture et histoire, je suis sûr que ça doit être une région intéressante.

Why do we actually need that whole expression in that phrase and what does it really mean? I know that **que** can usually be translated into English simply as **that** and, I'd say, it certainly makes sense to me that it's there. At least, its use there seems to be justified. However, I'm not as sure about the pronoun **en**'s role there. What's its purpose there?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*En* is not a pronoun here, but a preposition. If you leave out the part "surtout que", it may make more sense:

> En ce moment, je réagis très mal aux bruits

*En ce moment* simply means "at this moment".

*Surtout que* is a familiar phrase, used rather in spoken French. It is used to insist on a particular cause or contributing factor. You can translate it as "especially since" or "especially as".